# Hibernate/JPA - one primary key parent to composite key child

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

Whats wrong in my jpa mapping, im trying to map the parent class with one primary key to the child class with composite key, but it seems its inserting in the wrong table, it already generate 2 table but unfortunately i didn't bind the foreign key(policy_value_summary_id)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POLICY_VALUE_SUMMARY")
public class PolicyValueSummary {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="POLICY_VALUE_SUMMARY_ID")
    private Long policyValueSummaryId;

    @MapsId("policyValueSummaryId")
    @OneToMany
    private Set<PolicyValue> policyValues;
}
```

the child class have composite keys with one is the parent id.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POLICY_VALUE")
public class PolicyValue {

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "policyValueSummaryId", column = @Column(name = "POLICY_VALUE_SUMMARY_ID")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "planAtrId", column = @Column(name = "PLAN_ATR_ID")) })
    private PolicyValuePk policyValuePk;

}
```

This is my child class composite keys.

```
@Embeddable
public class PolicyValuePk implements Serializable {

    private Long policyValueSummaryId;

    private Long planAtrId;
}
```

Im trying to save the policy summary value(parent) with the policy value(child class) like this

```
        PolicyValuePk pk = new PolicyValuePk();
        pk.setPlanAtrId(Long.valueOf("1"));

        Set<PolicyValue> policyValues = new HashSet<>();
        policyValues.add(new PolicyValue(pk));

        PolicyValueSummary summary = new PolicyValueSummary();
        summary.setPolicyValues(policyValues);

        repo.save(summary);
```

Here is the error that being output to me

```
Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
Hibernate: insert into policy_value_summary (policy_value_summary_id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into policy_value_summary_policy_values (policy_value_summary_policy_value_summary_id, policy_values_plan_atr_id, policy_values_policy_value_summary_id) values (?, ?, ?)
WARN 6880 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 972, SQLState: 42000
ERROR 6880 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00972: identifier is too long
```

Answer (score 0):

No, prior to Oracle version 12.2, identifiers are not allowed to exceed 30 characters in length. See the document

```
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223
```

But from  from version 12.2 they can be up to 128 bytes long

Comment: but i already add the annotation @Table(name = "POLICY_VALUE") for policy values but it keeps inserting to the wrong table and columns(it concatenates the parent class to its child table and columns)